# CRUD operations on many to many relationship using entity framework core 2.0 code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have many to many relationship between computer and User. Unfortunately, there are not many examples of CRUD operations on many-to-many relationships. Most importantly adding and deleting. I tried like computer.ComputerUser.Add(), it works but deleting is confusing for me. I don't even know if I am doing it correctly. Your insights will be helpful. Thank you

```
// a computer can have one or more Users registered to access
public class Computer
{

    [Key]
    public Guid ComputerId { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }       
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;        
    public virtual ICollection<ComputerUser> ComputerUser { get; set; }

    public Computer()
    {
        this.ComputerUser = new HashSet<ComputerUser>();
    }
}
// an user can have access to one or more computers
public class User
{
   [Key]
   public Guid   GatekeeperUserId { get; set; } 
   public  string Name { get; set; }      
   public virtual ICollection<ComputerUser> ComputerUser { get; set; }

    public GatekeeperUser()
    {
        this.ComputerUser= new HashSet<ComputerUser>();
    }
}

// Joining table 
    [Key]
    public Guid ComputerId { get; set; }
    public  Computer Computer { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid  UserId { get; set; }
    public  User User { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Id of Computer or User which you want to remove from many-to-many relation.
You can call:

```
private DeleteComputerUser(User user, Guid computerId)
{
    var computerUser = _dbContext.ComputerUser.SingleOrDefault(computerUser=>
        computerUser.UserId == user.GatekeeperUserId
        && computerUser.ComputerId ==  computerId);
    if (computerUser  != null) 
    {
        _dbContext.ComputerUser.Remove(computerUser);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now relation between user and computer with specific id is gone.

Comment: Oh,so I have to add ComputerUser  to DbSet? Can't I do that through navigation

Comment: Yes, this table should be also in DbSet

Comment: is there a way I can split ComputerUser bridge table into two tables to store more info in each? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What's the confusion? It works like any other entity:

```
user.ComputerUser.Remove(computerUser);
```

I think you're getting hung up on the M2M. In fact, this is really not a true M2M. You've got a one to many from `User` to `ComputerUser` and a one to many from `Computer` to `ComputerUser`. As a result, it works like removing any other entity from any other collection.

Comment: Thank you Chris. How can I get computerUser before I get pass it to remove method?